# Scroll-snap-stop not working when scroll is fast ( aggresive scroll )

Tags: html, css

```
.home-component {
  width: 100%;
  height: 93vh;
  top : 7vh ;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

app-card {
  scroll-snap-align: start !important;
  scroll-snap-stop : always !important;
  -webkit-scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

I have a container/wrapper element : home-component and I have a component app-card whose list is contained within the wrapper. I have implemented the CSS to stop at each app-card , the code works when the scroll is light but when I scroll with speed , the scroll does not stop at the next app-card element.

I have already tried to implement the same for horizontal scroll and different align positions , but the code doesn't work.